# rc.d script looks for my binary in /run/daemons

Tags: bash, archlinux

EDIT: I am following [this example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Writing_rc.d_scripts).

Trying to write an archlinux rc.d script for mongod. I put my binaries in `/usr/bin`. Here is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# import predefined functions
. /etc/rc.conf
. /etc/rc.d/functions

# Point to the binary
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod

# Get the ARGS from the conf
. /etc/conf.d/crond

# Function to get the process id
PID=$(get_pid $DAEMON)

case "$1" in
   start)
    stat_busy "Starting $DAEMON"
    # Check the PID exists - and if it does (returns 0) - do no run
    [ -z "$PID" ] && $DAEMON $ARGS $> /dev/null
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        add_daemon $DAEMON
        stat_done
    else
        stat_fail
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
   stop)
        stat_busy "Stopping $DAEMON"
    kill -HUP $PID &>/dev/null

    rm_daemon $DAEMON
    stat_done
    ;;
   restart)
        $0 stop
    sleep 1
    $0 start
    ;;
    *)
        echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac
```

The problem is that when I do `sudo rc.d start mongod`, I get the following error:

```
:: Starting /usr/bin/mongod                                                                                   
[BUSY] /etc/rc.d/functions: line 203: /run/daemons//usr/bin/mongod: No such file or directory
                                                                                                              [DONE]
```

Comment: What is line 203 of `/etc/rc.d/functions`?

Comment: Nevermind! The problem was I used `$>` instead of `&>`.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error.

I used `$>` instead of `&>` on the line:

```
[ -z "$PID" ] && $DAEMON $ARGS $> /dev/null
```